# Flutter doctor does not see vs code ,VS code does not detect flutter/bin

Tags: android, ubuntu, flutter, visual-studio-code, sdk

I downloaded flutter sdk and placed it in /home/sony/flutter/bin 
i installed vs code and installed flutter and dart dependencies, and tried to create new project , but i saw problem  "Could not find a Flutter SDK. Please ensure flutter is installed and in your PATH (you may need to restart)." i showed location of my flutter sdk throught the button LOCATE SDK in vs code (/home/sony/flutter/bin ) and vs code cannot find flutter sdk(

flutter doctor shows this thing "Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.7.8+hotfix.4, on Linux, locale en_US.UTF-8)

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.2)
[!] Android Studio (version 3.4)
    ✗ Flutter plugin not installed; this adds Flutter specific functionality.
    ✗ Dart plugin not installed; this adds Dart specific functionality.
[!] IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition (version 2019.2)
    ✗ Flutter plugin not installed; this adds Flutter specific functionality.
    ✗ Dart plugin not installed; this adds Dart specific functionality.
[!] Connected device
    ! No devices available

[image]

Problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was a bug in the **Locate SDK** functionality in a previous version of the Dart/Flutter extensions for VS Code that should be fixed in v3.4:

https://dartcode.org/releases/v3-4/#other

[#1896](https://github.com/Dart-Code/Dart-Code/issues/1896): The Locate SDK button now correctly saves the folder you select to your user settings.

Please update to the latest version and if you still have that problem, file an issue on GitHub. Thanks!